# Comparative Simple Map in Visual c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, dictionary, visual-c++, location

I'm writing a GUI for remote controling of few devices, using visual studio c++ 2017. I have the devices' approximate location and I want to show them on a simple map (not actual map or google map api) something like below:
[image: simple map template]

I'm not sure which item or container should I use to obtain this. I would be very grateful if you'd have any suggestion on how to implement this map.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you currently using for your UI (MS-Windows GUI, Console, something else)? There is nothing in standard C++ to draw graphics (like you want) on a screen. Am assuming you are not asking for a external library recommendation as that would be off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm using visual studio graphics, so I guess MS-Windows to be specific. I'm more looking for an item from toolbox list of vs to use.